# Interprete Expected Value $\frac{E(X)}{n \cdot \log n}$ and Variance $\frac{V(X)}{n}$

Tags: stochastic-analysis

in my stochastics homework i have to plot the expected value and variance of a given random variable.

Expected value $\frac{E(X)}{n \cdot \log n}$ converges against 1.3 for $n \rightarrow \infty$ and variance $\frac{V(X)}{n}$ is constant at around 0.35. What can i interprete from that?

Comment: Do you mean $X_n$ is a sequence of random variables such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{E[X_n]}{n \log(n)} = 1.3$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{Var(X_n)}{n} = 0.35$? And, what type of thing are you looking to conclude?

Comment: Yes. The excercise says i need to conclude what i can read from this.